# How to force start and restart service on specify tty

Tags: systemd

I want to run my python program on tty3.
I created a.service.
How to force systemd to run and restart on the same tty?
Now i have situation that after restart program is running on active tty.

What should I write to:
StandardInput?
Now i Have StandardInput=tty-force

Regards

Regards?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. A service is not something that run on a particular terminal. Seems a [xy problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem), please tell us your goal

Comment: I am going to run python program under systemd. Program is closed into loop and should restart after error. When error occure i am logoff from terminal and i have to log in again to check status. I would like to run program on the terminal tty3 and all restart should run on the same terminal.

Comment: Logging out is annoying.

Comment: Normally, a service would not use _any_ tty, but log to its own log file or use _syslog_. Keep in mind that you might some day need to access it from the outside via _ssh_ and not have physical access to any of the consoles.